# C++ how to read a line with delimiter until the end of each line?

Tags: c++, getline

Hi I need to read a file that looks like this...

```
1|Toy Story (1995)|Animation|Children's|Comedy
2|Jumanji (1995)|Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3|Grumpier Old Men (1995)|Comedy|Romance
4|Waiting to Exhale (1995)|Comedy|Drama
5|Father of the Bride Part II (1995)|Comedy
6|Heat (1995)|Action|Crime|Thriller
7|Sabrina (1995)|Comedy|Romance
8|Tom and Huck (1995)|Adventure|Children's
9|Sudden Death (1995)|Action
```

As you can see the type of each movie can vary from 1 type to many...I wonder how could I read those until the end of each line?

I'm currently doing:

```
void readingenre(string filename,int **g)
{

    ifstream myfile(filename);
    cout << "reading file "+filename << endl;
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        string item;
        string name;
        string type;
        while(!myfile.eof())
        {
            getline(myfile,item,'|');
            //cout <<item<< "\t";
            getline(myfile,name,'|');
            while(getline(myfile,type,'|'))
            {
                cout<<type<<endl;
            }
            getline(myfile,type,'\n');
        }
        myfile.close();
        cout << "reading genre file finished" <<endl;
    }
}
```

the result is not what I want...It looks like:

```
Animation
Children's
Comedy
2
Jumanji (1995)
Adventure
Children's
Fantasy
3
Grumpier Old Men (1995)
Comedy
Romance
```

So it doesn't stop at the end of each line...How could I fix this?

Comment: Read the genre part without specifying a delimiter (i.e. using the default delimiter `'\n'`) and then split the result with `'|'`.

Comment: The code does exactly what you asked. What do you expect??

Comment: @Leon thank you! What function should I use to split the result with '|'?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard function. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: Yes this is not a CSV file but it is a delimited file so the same approach works. You just have to change `,` to `|` where appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Attempting to parse this input file one field at a time is the wrong approach.

This is a text file. A text file consists of lines terminated by newline characters. `getline()` by itself, is what you use to read a text file, with newline-terminated lines:

```
while (std::getline(myfile, line))
```

And not:

```
while(!myfile.eof())
```

[which is always a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

So now you have a loop that reads each line of text. A `std::istringstream` can be constructed inside the loop, containing the line just read:

```
   std::istringstream iline(line);
```

and then you can use `std::getline()`, with this `std::istringstream` with the optional delimiter character overriden to `'|'` to read each field in the line.